# Switching between date and time formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to provide an opportunity to change the date and time format in the user profile. Default is US format.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Rather than default to en-us, would it be better to check what Accept-Language they sent you in their request header?

Comment: It's a good idea. Perhaps I'll try to implement it. Could you suggest any sources to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you've got two options:

1. Use I18n. There's lots of good quality locale files [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n), then you can store a locale against the user (e.g. as an attribute on the user model). Then you can use localize to set the format: `I18n.l(time, :locale => user.locale)`
2. Store the date and time format string in the users profile and use those values to set the displayed date/time: `time.strftime(user.time_format)` where user.time_format is something like `%HH:%MM:%SS %dd/%mm/%yyyy`